# AS3: Access variable outside of function

Tags: actionscript-3

This issue is driving me nuts and I don't know what I'm missing here. This is my code:

```html
package  {
 
 import flash.display.*;
 import flash.text.*;
 import flash.events.*;
 import flash.net.*;
 import flash.xml.*; 
 
 public class PopUp extends Sprite {
  
  public var container:Array = new Array();

  public function PopUp() {
   
   var contentXML:XML = new XML(); 
   var XML_URL:String = "./content/content.xml"; 
   var contentXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
   var contentLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(contentXMLURL); 
   contentLoader.addEventListener("complete", FuncXML);
   
   function FuncXML(event:Event):void { 
    contentXML = XML(contentLoader.data);
    for each (var item in contentXML.item) {
     
     var txtbox:Sprite = new Sprite();
     txtbox.graphics.beginFill(0x444444, 0.9);
     txtbox.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 15, 15)
     txtbox.graphics.endFill();
     txtbox.name = "txtbox_"+item.settings.target;
     addChild(txtbox);
     container.push(txtbox);
    }
    trace(container.length); // Returns 2
   }
  trace(container.length); // Returns 0
  }

 }
 
}
```

The final version of this code should create text boxes from the contents of an xml file, but I can't get the content out of the function "FuncXML". I tried this with trace. The trace inside the function returns the correct length of "container", which is 2. Outside the function, the trace returns 0. Could you please tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was explained in other answer, your second trace will be executed before your first trace in the inner function. I happens because URLLoader is not instant, some time is needed for data to load. So you must wait until it finishes the work. You can wait for specific events as described in this document: [URLLoader Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html).
Below I can suggest some basic example of what you might want to do:

```
public class PopUp extends Sprite {

    public var container:Array = new Array();
    // Class constructor       
    public function PopUp() {

    }

    public function prepareAndLoad():void {
        var XML_URL:String = "./content/content.xml"; 
        var contentXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL); 
        var contentLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
        contentLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoadComplete);
        // good practice here would be to expect errors as well:
        contentLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
        contentLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onError);

        contentLoader.load(contentXMLURL);
    }
    private function onError(e:ErrorEvent):void {
        trace("Error");
        // maybe you want to handle this situation somehow.
    }

    private function onXMLLoadComplete(event:Event):void { 
        var contentXML:XML = XML(event.target.data);
        for each (var item in contentXML.item) {
            var txtbox:Sprite = new Sprite();
            txtbox.graphics.beginFill(0x444444, 0.9);
            txtbox.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, 100, 100, 15, 15)
            txtbox.graphics.endFill();
            txtbox.name = "txtbox_"+item.settings.target;
            addChild(txtbox);
            container.push(txtbox);
        }
        trace(container.length);
        // here your XML is loaded and processed. Dispatch an event to notify that job is done and container is not empty.
        dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your project you can create an instance of this popup:

```
//...
var popUp:PopUp = new PopUp();
popUp.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPopUpReady);
popUp.prepareAndLoad();
//...
private function onPopUpReady(e:Event):void {
    var popUp:PopUp = e.target as PopUp;
    trace(popUp.container.length); // Ready and loaded.
} 
//...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But how can I access the array "container" from outside of the class? I tried it with in my main file: 
`var newTxt:PopUp = new PopUp(); 
trace(newTxt.container.length); `
But it returns 0 again.

Comment: pay attention to the answer above given by Andrea. At the moment when you tracing the length of the array is 0 because your XML is not loaded yet.

Comment: @patrickhoehn I've updated my answer, please take a look. Hope it would help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will try this next week!

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Now that I see how I have to construct my functions, it seems so simple :D

Answer (score 2):

Reading your code I can see that the second `trace(container.length);` returns 0 simply because it is called **before** the "first" `trace(container.length);`.

You can understand it if you see that the function `FuncXML` is only declared and added as listener callback (or handler) before the second trace, but since you are in an **asynchronous** context you will never know if the `FuncXML` content will be executed before the second "trace" call.

In particular you have two functions flows that runs in parallels: `PopUp` flow `FuncXML` flow, but you are assuming that they are consequential.

Hope this could help you

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned before, you are looking for the items before they are loaded.
You should wait until they are loaded and ready, and then handle them on the stage or elsewhere.
I would handle this situation like this:
On your main file:

```
var newTxt:PopUp = new PopUp({
    onReady_func: handlePopUp //pass the function to PopUp class as a parameter
}); 

// this function will be called whenever PopUp is ready
function handlePopUp(){
    trace(newTxt.container.length);
}
```

In the PopUp class:

```
...
// the $config object contains setup parameters 
public function PopUp($config) {
    ...
    function FuncXML(event:Event):void { 
       ...
       //  Everything is ready. Lets tell them.
       $config.onReady_func(); // this call should be in the last line of funcXML
    }
```

Comment: Couple of 'smells' here, imho: 1 - mixed camel case and underscore notations. 2 - passing callbacks in JS style instead of using typed argument. Also what's the point of using callback here instead of native event?

Comment: I'm not aware of those 2 rules. Are they personal? If not, please provide some references.

Comment: As I said it's absolutely personal opinion based on observations and personal experience gained in multiple fairly big projects.

Comment: You just gave a perfect misjudgment reference: "I downvoted because I can"

Comment: Pretty strange reaction. Your code is not a good example on my point of view, that's why I downvoted it. And I have a reason behind it. I suggest reading some coding guidelines to be aware of this rules (and many other useful rules). Some recommendations can be found here: http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/index.php/AS3_Coding_Standards. But it's never a mandatory, you can write in any way you like. Voting gives other people a possibility to react on your code. That's what I did, since I don't agree with the style you introduced.

Comment: Your reason is obscured. And those rules you mentioned before, they do not exist.

Comment: Once again. You introduced a piece of bad code. Even if the naming style will be What_EVER_uLIke, this code will be still pretty bad. The main reason is that you give a possibility to make a mistake and this mistake will be discovered only when the code will be executed. And you are free to do that in your own projects, but it's not a good example for any novice.

Comment: All the reasons you wrote above are personal, irrelevant and misleading. You should stop down-voting for those reasons.